# Using substitution variables in table name

Tags: oracle, plsql, substitution

My issue is easy, I want to find out if what I am trying to do can be done or not.

I have tables like this : `detailcro1, detailcro2, detailcro3` ... I want to use a substitution var for some automatic process.

I wrote

```
DEFINE TT = 'detailcro'
select * from &TT||'2';
```

and as a result I have `ORA-00933:.`

Can I create such a query ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to usu a dot notation at the end of the variable

```
SQL> select * from &TT.l;
Enter value for tt: dua
old   1: select * from &TT.l
new   1: select * from dual

D
-
X
```

so

```
SQL> DEFINE TT = 'detailcro';
SQL> select * from &TT.2;
old   1: select * from &TT.2
new   1: select * from detailcro2

no rows selected
```

Comment: Thank you Robert That Works as i wanted it. is there any doc for the use of the '.' i orcale ? thank you again.

Comment: Just this : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB 'Where and How to Use Substitution Variables'